# Strip comments from text except for comment char between quotes

Tags: regex, comments

I'm trying to build a regexp for removing comments from a configuration file. Comments are marked with the `;` character. For example:

```
; This is a comment line
keyword1 keyword2 ; comment
keyword3 "key ; word 4" ; comment
```

The difficulty I have is ignoring the comment character when it's placed between quotes.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I've created something the simple way, without a regexp, parsing each line character for character. But I'm trying to understand how to solve this kind of problem using a regexp.

Answer (score 2):

You could try matching a semicolon only if it's followed by an even number of quotes:

```
;(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$).*
```

Be sure to use this regex with the `Singleline` option turned *off* and the `Multiline` option turned *on*.

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> t = """; This is a comment line
... keyword1 keyword2 ; comment
... keyword3 "key ; word 4" ; comment"""
>>> regex = re.compile(';(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$).*', re.MULTILINE)
>>> regex.sub("", t)
'\nkeyword1 keyword2 \nkeyword3 "key ; word 4" '
```

Answer (score 0):

No regex :)

```
$ grep -E -v '^;' input.txt
keyword1 keyword2 ; comment
keyword3 "key ; word 4" ; comment
```

Comment: the `; comment` in the two output sentence should be removed, too.

Comment: This is also doesn't work if the comment is preceded by whitespace (or, for that matter, anything).

Answer (score 0):

You may use regexp to get all strings out first, replace them with some place-holder, and then simply cut off all `\$.*`, and replace back the strings at last :)

Comment: Are you serious? You'd need to keep track exactly which strings you took from which positions, calculate how these positions change after you've removed the comments, and re-insert them?

Comment: No, no need to keep position axies, but as I already said, place a place-holder such as `[STRING#1]` or anything that would not conflict with his original string.

Comment: Or, in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python gives some way better, but the key point is the same: split the strings first

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
("[^"]*")*.*(;.*)
```

First, match any number of text between quotes, then match a ;. If the ; is between quotes it will be matches by the first group, not by the second group.

Comment: What if the line is `"Text; in" and between "quotes; plus" semicolons; this is the comment`?

Answer (score 0):

I (somewhat accidentally) came up with a working regex:

`replace(/^((?:[^'";]*(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")?)*)[ \t]*;.*$/gm, '$1')`

I wanted:

- remove single line comments at start of line or end of line,
- to use single and double quotes,
- the ability to have just *one* quote in a comment: **that**`'`**s** useful (but accept `"` as well)
  (so matching on a balanced set (even number) of quotes after a comment-delimiter as in  [Tim Pietzcker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9018769/588079) was not suitable),
- leave comment-delimiter `;` alone in *correctly* (closed) quoted 'strings'
- mix quoting style
- multiple quoted strings (and comments in/after comments)
- nest single/double quotes in resp. double/single quoted 'strings'
- data to work on is like valid ini-files (or assembly), as long as it doesn't contain escaped quotes or regex-literals etc.

Lacking look-back on javascript I thought it might be an idea to *not match comments* (and replace them with `''`), *but match on data preceding the comment* and then replace the full match data with the sub-match data.
One could envision this concept on a line by line basis (so replace the full line with the match, thereby 'loosing' the comment), *BUT* the multiline parameter doesn't seem to work exactly that way (at least in the browser).

`[^'";]*` starts eating any characters from the 'start' that are *not* `'";`.
<sup>(Completely counter-intuitive (to me), `[^'";\r\n]*` will *not* work.)</sup>

`(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")?` is a non-capturing group matching zero or one set of `quote any chars quote` <sup>(and `(?:(['"])[^\2]*\2)?` in `/^((?:[^'";]*(?:(['"])[^\2]*\2)?)*)[ \t]*;.*$/gm` or

`(?:(['"])[^\2\r\n]*\2)?` in `/^((?:[^'";]*(?:(['"])[^\2\r\n]*\2)?)*)[ \t]*;.*$/gm` (although mysteriously better) do **not** work (broke on `db 'WDVPIVAlQEFQ;WzRcU',"hi;hi",0xfe,"'as`), but not adding another capturing group for re-use in the match is a good thing as they come with penalties anyway).</sup>

The above combo is placed in a non-capturing group which may repeat zero or more times and it's result is placed in a capturing group `1` to pass along.

That leaves us with `[ \t]*;.*` which 'simply' matches zero or more spaces and tabs followed by a semicolon, followed by zero or more chars that are not a new line. Note how `;` is NOT optional !!!

To get a better idea of how this (multi-line parameter) works, hit the `exp` button in the demo below.

```js
function demo(){
  var elms=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  var str=elms[0].value;
  elms[1].value=str.replace( /^((?:[^'";]*(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")?)*)[ \t]*;.*$/gm
                           , '$1'
                           )
                   .replace( /[ \t]*$/gm, ''); //optional trim
}


function demo_exp(){
  var elms=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  var str=elms[0].value;
  elms[1].value=str.replace( /^((?:[^'";]*(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")?)*)[ \t]*;.*$/gm
                           , '**S**$1**E**'  //to see start and end of match.
                           );
}
```

```html
<textarea  style="width:98%;height:150px" onscroll="this.nextSibling.scrollTop=this.scrollTop;">
; This is a comment line
keyword1 keyword2 ; comment
keyword3 "key ; word 4" ; comment

  
"Text; in" and between "quotes; plus" semicolons; this is the comment
  
  ; This is a comment line
  keyword1 keyword2 ; comment
  keyword3 'key ; word 4' ; comment and one quote ' ;see it?
  
_b64decode:
        db    0x83,0xc6,0x3A ; add   si, b64decode_end - _b64decode ;39
        push  'a'   
        pop   di 
  
        cmp   byte [si], 0x2B ; '+'


b64decode_end:
        ;append base64 data here
        ;terminate with printable character less than '+'
        db 'WDVPIVAlQEFQ;WzRcU',"hi;hi",0xfe,"'as;df'" ;'haha"
;"end'
  
</textarea><textarea style="width:98%;height:150px" onscroll="this.previousSibling.scrollTop=this.scrollTop;">
result here
</textarea>
<br><button onclick="demo()">remove comments</button><button onclick="demo_exp()">exp</button>
```

Hope this helps.

**PS:** Please comment valid examples if and where this might break! Since I generally agree (from extensive personal experience) that it is impossible to reliably remove comments using regex (especially higher level programming languages), my gut is still saying this can't be fool-proof. However I've been throwing existing data and crafted 'what-ifs' at it for over 2 hours and couldn't get it to break (, which I'm usually very good at).