# Handling spaces inside path variable python

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a string as follows

`command= "copy1 "D:\path1\program Files" "c:\program Files\path1" copy2 "D:\path2\program Files" "c:\program Files\path2""`

Note that both copy1 and copy2 are inside the string. My intention was to write each copy process insde an xml file as follows:

```
        <copyFiles>
               <copy1>
                    <Sourcepath>D:\path1\program Files</Sourcepath>
                    <DestPath>c:\program Files\path1</DestPath>
                </copy1>

                 <copy2>
                    <Sourcepath>D:\path2\program Files</Sourcepath>
                    <DestPath>c:\program Files\path2</DestPath>
                  </copy2>

         <copyFiles>
```

I tried to create a list of each paramter by splitting the string using spaces as follows:

`Copyparamlist=command.split(' ')`

But I am geeting the xml as follows:

```
        <copyFiles>
               <copy1>
                    <Sourcepath>D:\path1\program</Sourcepath>
                    <DestPath>c:\program</DestPath>
                </copy1>

                 <copy2>
                    <Sourcepath>D:\path2\program</Sourcepath>
                    <DestPath>c:\program</DestPath>
                  </copy2>

         <copyFiles>
```

The contents of my list should be as follows: 
`["copy1", "D:\path1\program Files", "c:\program Files\path1", "copy2",
 "D:\path2\program Files]", "c:\program Files\path2"]`

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what exactly you want, but it looks like you want to split the string as follows:

```
a = 'this "is a string" with "4 elements"'
split = magic_splitter(a)  #How to write magic splitter?
print split  #['this', 'is a string', 'with', '4 elements']
```

If that's the case, what you want is to use the fantastic function `shlex.split`

```
print shlex.split(a) #['this', 'is a string', 'with', '4 elements']
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the output you want? You can use `join` to put it in whatever format you want. For example, to simply remove the spaces, use

```
Copyparamlist=''.join(command.split(' '))
```

Or if you want to replace them with %20, use

```
Copyparamlit='%20'.join(command.split(' '))
```

Comment: i can't use 
Copyparamlist=''.join(command.split(' ')) because it will join all the string and same is the case with
Copyparamlit='%20'.join(command.split(' '))

The contents of my list should be as follows 

[copy1,D:\path1\program Files,c:\program Files\path1,copy2,D:\path2\program Files],c:\program Files\path2]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another separator other than space ... 
for example ... you can use for example the quote a separator using something as

```
CopyParam = command.split('"')
```

And should I understand the format of string command
as copyName "Source" "Destination" ...
You can loop on the list of triplets ...
like

```
for i in xrange(0, len(CopyParam), 3): 
    copyname, sourcepath, destpath = CopyParam[i], CopyParam[i + 1], CopyParam[i + 2]
    # Do the code to transfer it to XML here ..
```

You might need to remove the empty elements from the list first ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your command string is actually specified as;

```
command='copy1 "something with spaces" "somewhere else" copy2 "this thing" "elsewhere"'
```

if your commands are always copy commands, maybe look at splitting on the word 'copy' and working with the resulting list,

```
command.split('copy')
['','1 "something with spaces" "somewhere else" ','2 "this thing" "elsewhere"']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread might have what you're looking for. You're probably going to have to use regular expressions if you're trying to ignore splits that are in quotes.

[How to split but ignore separators in quoted strings, in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python)

Try this code:

```
import re
PATTERN = re.compile(r'''((?:[^ "']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''')
command = PATTERN.split(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

With this, it can be easily managed as a dictionary:

```
import shlex
split = shlex.split(commandlist)
commands = dict(zip(split[::3], zip(split[1::3], split[2::3])))
```

Explanation:
Given the string 'copyname "source" "dest" copyname2 "source2" "dest2"'...

split = shlex.split() will split the string in the format `['copyname', 'source', 'dest', 'copyname2', 'source2','dest2']`

`split[::3]` is doing something called splicing. This implicitly says 'Starting at the 0 index, give me every third item. `split[::3]` will equal `['copyname', 'copyname2']`. The splicing doesn't stop there, though. `split[1::3]` says to start at index 1 and then give every third element after that. It will return all of the sources.

The `zip` function is a unique one. Given lists `l1=['a','b','c']` and `l2=[1,2,3]`, `zip(l1,l2)` will equal `[('a',1),('b',2), ('c',3)]`.

`zip(split[1::3], split[2::3])` will equal `[('source', 'dest'), ('source2', 'dest2')]`.

`zip(split[::3], zip(split[1::3], split[2::3]))` will equal `[('copyname',('source','dest')), ('copyname2',('source2','dest2'))]`.

The `dict` function will then convert each key/value pair (`copyname` and `('source','dest')`) in the given list into a dictionary.

The `commands` variable is now in the format `{'copyname': ('source', 'dest'), ...}`
To write to the xml, simply iterate through the dictionary.

Pro Tip: When iterating through a dictionary with `for`, each item will be a key.

And if you want, you can just use `for copyname, source, dest in zip(split[::3], split[1::3], split[2::3])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sample:

```
import shlex
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def my_parser(s):
    command = []
    for item in shlex.split(s):
        if item.startswith('copy'):
            if command:            # any previous command was collected?
                yield command      # output one parsed command
            command = [ item ]     # start collecting new command
        else:
            command.append(item)   # collect another argument    

    if command:                    # if anything was collected
        yield command              # output the last parsed command


cmd = r'copy1 "D:\path1\program Files" "c:\program Files\path1" copy2 "D:\path2\program Files" "c:\program Files\path2"'

# Just to show what are the parsed command in the lists
for command in my_parser(cmd):
    print command

# Alternatively, constructing the XML.
e = etree.Element('copyFiles')    # root element
tree = etree.ElementTree(e)
root = tree.getroot()             # now the same as e 

for command in my_parser(cmd):
    assert len(command) == 3
    assert command[0].startswith('copy')

    e = etree.Element(command[0])  # the command name becomes the tag name 

    src = etree.Element('Sourcepath')  # subelement
    src.text = command[1]

    dst =  etree.Element('DestPath')   # subelement
    dst.text = command[2]

    e.append(src)                  # subelement appended to its parent
    e.append(dst)                  # subelement appended to its parent

    root.append(e)                 # command appended to the root element

tree.write('output.xml')
```

It prints:

```
['copy1', 'D:\\path1\\program Files', 'c:\\program Files\\path1']
['copy2', 'D:\\path2\\program Files', 'c:\\program Files\\path2']
```

and it produces `output.xml` with the following content (as one line, wrapped manually here):

```
<copyFiles><copy1><Sourcepath>D:\path1\program Files</Sourcepath>
<DestPath>c:\program Files\path1</DestPath></copy1>
<copy2><Sourcepath>D:\path2\program Files</Sourcepath>
<DestPath>c:\program Files\path2</DestPath></copy2></copyFiles>
```