# python split by comma and ignore the one in quotes

Tags: python, split

Currently, I want to parse a csv file which has 4 items per line and separate by comma. For example:

`1, "2,3", 4, 5`

How can I split it into :

`[1,"2,3",4,5]`

I try to use `csv.reader`, but the outcome still in wrong way. Can anyone help?
THX!

Comment: How did you try to use `csv.reader`, and how was the result wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

`csv.reader` will not do type conversion, but something like this perhaps:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: data = ['1, "2,3", 4, 5']

In [3]: next(csv.reader(data, skipinitialspace=True))
Out[3]: ['1', '2,3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: If the OP does want the "natural" type conversion, either `list(ast.literal_eval(line))` or `json.loads('[{}]'.format(line))` should work.

Comment: @DSM - You are right. At the moment I answered more on a hunch that OP forgot the quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
[xxx.csv]
1, "2,3", 4, 5
"""

import re
f = open("xxx.csv")
line = f.readline() # line = '1, "2,3", 4, 5'
startUnit = False # " is for start or end
token = ""
answer=[]
for i in line:
    if startUnit==False and re.match("[0-9]", i):
        answer.append(int(i))
    elif i=='"':
        if startUnit==True:
            answer.append(token)
        startUnit = not startUnit
    elif startUnit==True:
        token+=i
    elif startUnit==False:
        token=""

print answer
```

This is simple example.
It can make other exceptions because the code is only for your example. (1, "2,3", 4, 5)
I hope it is helpful for you