# How to split a string based on comma as separator with comma within double quotes remaining as it is in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to separate a string based on comma, but when the string is within double quotes the commas should be kept as it is. For that I wrote the following code. However, the code given below does not seem to work. Can someone please help me figure out as to what the error is?

```
>>> from csv import reader
>>> l='k,<livesIn> "Dayton,_Ohio"'
>>> l1=[]
>>> l1.append(l)
>>> for line1 in reader(l1):
        print line1
```

The output which I am getting is:

```
['k', '<livesIn> "Dayton', '_Ohio"']
```

Whereas I want the output as: `['k', '<livesIn> "Dayton,_Ohio"']` i.e. I don't want `"Dayton,_Ohio"` to get separated.

Comment: You need to configure the dialect parameter. http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split but ignore separators in quoted strings, in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python)

Comment: Why are you using csv to parse a string, and not a csv file?

Comment: @bozdoz That's fine, however a better way is `reader(StringIO(l))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a way.

```
>>> from csv import reader
>>> l='k,<livesIn> "Dayton,_Ohio"'
>>> l1=[]
>>> l1.append(l)
>>> for line in reader(l1):
...   print list((line[0], ','.join(line[1:])))
... 
['k', '<livesIn> "Dayton,_Ohio"']
```