# Python - How to ignore white spaces in double quotes while splitting a string?

Tags: python, string

I have my data as below

```
string = ' streptococcus 7120 "File  being  analysed" rd873 '
```

I tried to split the line using `n=string.split()` which gives the below result:

```
[streptococcus,7120,File,being,analysed,rd873]
```

I would  like to split the string ignoring white spaces in " "

```
# output expected :

[streptococcus,7120,File being analysed,rd873]
```

Comment: Is it possible that you will have nested quotes (e.g. `"File name "foo" being analyzed"`)?

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python).

Answer (score 4):

Use `re.findall` with a suitable regex. I'm not sure what your error cases look like (what if there are an odd number of quotes?), but:

```
filter(None, it.chain(*re.findall(r'"([^"]*?)"|(\S+)', ' streptococcus 7120 "File  being  analysed" rd873 "hello!" hi')))
> ['streptococcus',
   '7120',
   'File  being  analysed',
   'rd873',
   'hello!',
   'hi']
```

looks right.

Comment: Did you test this on OP's sample string? It doesn't do what you want it to do. (Well, now it does after you edited it.)

Answer (score 3):

You want `shlex.split`, which gives you the behavior you want with the quotes.

```
import shlex

string = ' streptococcus 7120 "File  being  analysed" rd873 '
items  = shlex.split(string)
```

This won't strip extra spaces embedded in the strings, but you can do that with a list comprehension:

```
items  = [" ".join(x.split()) for x in shlex.split(string)]
```

Look, ma, no regex!

Comment: Thanks a lot is there any another approach apart from using shlex

Comment: Well, there are many approaches to doing just about anything...

Comment: Shlex grabs single-quoted strings as well, I'm not sure whether or not that's intended.