# Remove " from regex result python

Tags: python, regex

So I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python) answer to get really close to what i need.

In my case I want to split on space but not when a part of the string is within quotes.

This is my code:

```
data = '"abc dfg" ab da'    
PATTERN = re.compile(r'''((?:[^ "']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''')
wordList = PATTERN.split(data)[1::2]
```

Gives wordList:

```
['"abc dfg"', 'ab', 'da']
```

How can I change the expression so that the string is without the extra quotes?

Like this:

```
['abc dfg', 'ab', 'da']
```

Comment: With regex or in anyway?

Comment: just replace quotes from the returned text with an empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to complicate your regex, simply iterate on the list and remove `"` from it. You can do that in many ways, for example using `strip('"')`.

By the way, you have much better solution:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('"abc dfg" ab da')
['abc dfg', 'ab', 'da']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> wordList = ['"abc dfg"', 'ab', 'da']
>>> wordList = [word.strip('"') for word in wordList]
>>> wordList
['abc dfg', 'ab', 'da']
```

Comment: `[word.strip('"').strip("'") for word in wordList]`