# Python Concerning Nested Parentheses

Tags: python

The problem I'm facing is being able to take an string like "((1+4)) + (2-1) - 3" and turn it in a list with [((1+4)), (2-1), 3] in it. This would also apply to other amount of parentheses. I tried doing it with indexes and counting parentheses with no luck. Here is some code I have so far:

```
final = []
while("(" in string):
final.append(string[string.index("("):string.index(")")+1])
left = string[:string.index("(")]
right = string[string.index(")")+1:]
string = string.replace("+", ";")
string = string.replace("-", ";")
string = string.split(";")
for item in string:
   if item.strip() != "":
     final.append(item)
```

Comment: why is `3` included in the list?

Comment: needs to deal with stuff not nested in parentheses as well since this is a basic and plausible mathematical expression

Comment: don't you want something more like [1+4, 2-1, 3], getting rid of parentheses altogether?

Comment: naw, They get removed later on with other expression that print some other needed information.

Comment: This is uncomfortably close to parsing HTML with regex, and we [know how that ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

The regex (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) gives you the shortest and possibility the fastest solution. But, if you prefer a solution that is easier to read and understand try this one:

```
def split_expr(s):
    l = []
    p =0
    expr = ''
    for c in s:
        if c=='(': p+=1
        if c==')': p-=1
        if (p==0) and (c in '+-*/'):
            l.append(expr)
            expr = ''
        else:
            expr += c
    else:
        l.append(expr)
    return l
```

You can also see this post ([How to split but ignore separators in quoted strings, in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python)). It can inspire you for some more elegant solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use a regular expression for this one. This answer is probably not optimal, but take a look at how to use the `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\s+[\+\*\-\/]\s+")
>>> s = "((1+4)) + (2-1) - 3"
>>> for sub in regex.findall(s):
...     s = s.replace(sub, " ")
>>> s
'((1+4)) (2-1) 3'
>>> s.split()
['((1+4))', '(2-1)', '3']
```

So, we compile a regular expression using `re.compile`, this way we can use the regular expression again and again without having to compile it each time. Then we use `findall` to findall the substrings that satisfy the regular expression, then we take each substring and use the `replace` function on a string to replace it with a single space. We then use `split` with the default delimiter set to `" "` to split the string.

EDIT: Because I totally forgot, you can use `re.split`, which does all of the above in one fell swoop.

```
>>> s = "((1+4)) + (2-1) - 3"
>>> regex.split(s)
['((1+4))', '(2-1)', '3']
```

Thanks @BurhanKhalid :)

Comment: You might want to check with the OP on whether they basically want to just split on whitespace, but I get the feeling they don't.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac What if the `string` in this format `"((1 + 4)) + (2 - 1) - 3"`?

Comment: @gsb-eng Then you'd need a more complex regex to get the work done, preferably with `\)(\s+[\+\-\*\/]\s+)(\))?`, and replace group 1.

Comment: You could also replace this regex with a simple `[item for item in s.split() if item not in '+-*/']`. I don't think it solves the right problem at all.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Then offer an alternative answer.