# How to take double quouted value from a string

Tags: python

I have a string which I want to convert to a list where each element is delimited by commas.

For example `'test1,"test2,test3",test4'` will become `['test1', 'test2 test3', 'test4']`

Note that I do not want to split `test2` and `test3`

Comment: post ur attempts..

Comment: @Selcuk not really

Comment: @AnttiHaapala How about [How to split but ignore separators in quoted strings, in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2785755)

Answer (score 2):

Like the answer of TigerhawkT3, i use `csv.reader` too, but with 2 more parameters.

```
import csv

src_text = 'test1,"test2,test3",test4'
r = csv.reader([src_text], delimiter= ',', quotechar='"')
converted_list = next(r)
```

Output

```
>>> print converted_list
['test1', 'test2,test3', 'test4']
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a row from a CSV file. Use `csv.reader`.

```
>>> import csv
>>> lines = ['test1,"test2,test3",test4', 'testa,"testb,testc",testd']
>>> r = csv.reader(lines)
>>> list(r)
[['test1', 'test2,test3', 'test4'], ['testa', 'testb,testc', 'testd']]
```

Comment: I would like to know what is wrong or unhelpful about my answer to make it deserve a downvote, so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `split()` it by `"` first, replace the commas with spaces, `strip()` trailing whitespace, and remove empty elements (when the double quote is at the end). This would require quite a lot of iterations. Look at @TigerhawkT3's answer.

```
def split_string(s):
    ret = s.split('"')
    ret = [ " ".join(x.split(",")) for x in ret ]
    ret = [x.strip() for x in ret]
    ret = [ x for x in ret if x != ""]

    return ret
```