# pyspark split on delimiter ignoring double quotes using regex

Tags: regex, csv, pyspark

I am very new to spark. I am trying to play with rdds. So here is my basic rdd

```
rdd=sc.parallelize(['"ab,cd",9', 'xyz,6'])
```

Now if I want to split it on commas I do

```
rdd.map(lambda x:x.split(",")).collect()
```

which gives me

`[['ab', 'cd', '9'], ['xyz', '6']]`

Since I want to ignore the commas in between the text placed in "", I write

```
rdd.map(lambda x:x.split(",(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)")).collect()
```

which gives the output

`[['ab,cd,9'], ['xyz,6']]`
 (Thus this is not a duplicate question)

But I want the output similar to what I get with `.split(",")` like so

`[['ab,cd','9'], ['xyz','6']]`

I am not very good with regex and so I do not know how to manipulate it to get that output.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please format your question so it is readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split but ignore separators in quoted strings, in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python)

Comment: @pault, no it is not a duplicate and I have mentioned in my question that the answer in the link you gave doesn't work for my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787064/5858851) and modify the pattern for `,` instead of `;`:

```python
import re
pattern = r"""((?:[^,"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)"""
rdd.map(lambda x: re.split(pattern , x)[1::2]).collect()
#[['"ab,cd"', '9'], ['xyz', '6']]
```

The `[1::2]` means take every other item in the list, starting at index 1. More on [understanding python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).

This pattern matches fields (not the delimiter), so without the slice, you'd get:

```python
[['', '"ab,cd"', ',', '9', ''], ['', 'xyz', ',', '6', '']]
```

**Update**

If you only wanted to ignore the separator in between double quotes (and not single quotes), you can modify the pattern as follows:

```python
pattern = r"""((?:[^,"]|"[^"]*")+)"""
rdd=sc.parallelize(["xy'z,6",'"ab,cd",5'])
rdd.map(lambda x: re.split(pattern , x)[1::2]).collect()
#[["xy'z", '6'], ['"ab,cd"', '5']]
```

Comment: Wonderful worked perfectly for me. Although, I will take some time to understand this thoroughly. Thanks a lot

Comment: What if in my rdd I also have `'` like `rdd=sc.parallelize(["xy'z,6",'"ab,cd",5'])`

Comment: @user7623678 in that case you'd have to modify the pattern by removing the logic for single quotes. This should work: `pattern = r"""((?:[^,"]|"[^"]*")+)"""`