# Python parsing CSV string with possible sets

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I have a CSV string where some of the items might be enclosed by `{}` with commas inside. I wanted to collect the string values in a list.

What is the most pythonic way to collect the values in a list?

**Example 1:** `'a,b,c'`, expected output `['a', 'b', 'c']`

**Example 2:** `'{aa,ab}, b, c'`, expected output `['{aa,ab}','b','c']`

**Example 3:** `'{aa,ab}, {bb,b}, c'`, expected output `['{aa,ab}', '{bb,b}', 'c']`

I have tried to work with `s.split(',')`, it works for example 1 but will mess up for case 2 and 3.

I believe that this question ([How to split but ignore separators in quoted strings, in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python)) is very similar to my problem. But I can't figure out the proper regex syntax to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is very similar in fact:

```
import re
PATTERN = re.compile(r'''\s*((?:[^,{]|\{[^{]*\})+)\s*''')
data = '{aa,ab}, {bb,b}, c'
print(PATTERN.split(data)[1::2])
```

will give:

```
['{aa,ab}', '{bb,b}', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

A more readable way (at least to me) is to explain what you are looking for: either something between brackets { } or something that only contains alphanumeric characters:

```
import re 

examples = [
  'a,b,c',
  '{aa,ab}, b, c',
  '{aa,ab}, {bb,b}, c'
]

for example in examples:
  print(re.findall(r'(\{.+?\}|\w+)', example))
```

It prints

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['{aa,ab}', 'b', 'c']
['{aa,ab}', '{bb,b}', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is not necessary to use a regex, you can just use pure Python:

```
s = '{aa,ab}, {bb,b}, c'
commas = [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c == ',' and \
                                             s[:i].count('{') == s[:i].count('}')]
[s[2:b] for a, b in zip([-2] + commas, commas + [None])]
#['{aa,ab}', '{bb,b}', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple pure python approach replacing {} with "":

```
def parseCSV(string):

    results = []
    current = ''
    quoted = False
    quoting = False


    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        currentletter = string[i]

        if currentletter == '"':
            if quoted == True:
                if quoting == True:
                    current = current + currentletter
                    quoting = False 
                else:
                    quoting = True

            else:
                quoted = True
                quoting = False

        else:

            shouldCheck  = False

            if quoted == True:

                if quoting == True:
                    quoted = False
                    quoting = False

                    shouldCheck = True

                else:
                    current = current + currentletter

            else:
                shouldCheck = True

            if shouldCheck == True:
                if currentletter == ',':
                    results.append(current)
                    current = ''

                else:
                    current = current +  currentletter

    results.append(current)
    return results
```