# How to split but ignore separators in quoted and braced strings, in python?

Tags: python, string

I want to split a string on some delimiter but does not split quoted on braced string present in it. say semicolon.

```
eg . '1;2;"3;4"; [5;6];7'

['1','2','"3;4"','[5;6]','7']
```

Comment: Do you want to split on both commata and semicolons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split but ignore separators in quoted strings, in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python)

Comment: split on semicolon

Comment: @Unamata Sanatarai given link only handles quotes not braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regular expressions like so:

```python
import re

str = '''1;2;"3;4"; [5;6];7'''
matcher = re.compile(r'''(\".+?\"|\[.+?\]|\(.+?\)|\{.+?\}|[^\"[({]+?)(?:;|$)''')

print(matcher.findall(str)) # returns ['1', '2', '"3;4"', '[5;6]', '7']
```

This regex supports bracketing with ", [, (, { and the delimiter ;

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with the algorithmic way (it's far better do parse it with regular expression like monK_)

```py
def splitter(string):
    ignoreStart = ["\"", "["]
    ignoreEnd = ["\"",  "]"]

    separator = ";"
    result = []
    buffer = ""
    specialCase = None
    for char in string:
        edited = False
        if not specialCase and char in ignoreStart:
            specialCase = ignoreEnd[ignoreStart.index(char)]
            edited = True

        if specialCase != None or char != separator:
            buffer += char
            if not edited and char == specialCase:
                specialCase = None
        else:
            result.append(buffer)
            buffer = ""
    if buffer != "":
        result.append(buffer)
    return result


print(splitter('1;2;"3;4";[5;6];7'))
```

Output :

```py
['1', '2', '"3;4"', '[5;6]', '7']
```