# How to exclude end of lines while text is in quotes

Tags: python, csv, split

I have a csv file with something like that:

```
oneWordString,"string with spaces","string
  with
  some, lines",anotherString
```

This string is getting from a program so i can´t change the format.

I am expecting to get something like this:

```
['oneWordString','string with spaces','string
  with
  some, lines','anotherString']
```

Comment: Are you using the `String split()` method to process the csv data? It's probably easier to use the `pandas` library for this, pretty sure it supports for quoted string values that contain a carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files often include both quoted and unquoted strings, and this is allowed by a common [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180.html#section-1) for the format of CSV files. The best way to deal with both standard and (within reason) non-standard CSV files is to use Python's [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which deals well with most aspects of the file format. Don't try to split up the strings using `split` or regex - the `csv` module does this more reliably and easily.

```
import csv

# Make example file
with open("example.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write("""oneWordString,"string with spaces","string
      with
      some, lines",anotherString""")

# Read it back
with open("example.csv") as f:
    result = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Answer (score -1):

I modified an existing regex found on stackoverflow to solve your problem. I also believes it yields your desired outcome.

```
import re

str_1 = """oneWordString, 'string with spaces','string
  with
  some, lines',anotherString"""

example_1 = re.compile(r'''((?:[^,"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''')
print(example_1.split(str_1)[1::2])

['oneWordString', " 'string with spaces'", "'string\n  with\n  some, lines'", 'anotherString']

str_2 = '''oneWordString, "string with spaces","string
  with
  some, lines",anotherString'''

example_2 = re.compile(r'''((?:[^,"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''')
print(example_2.split(str_2)[1::2])

['oneWordString', ' "string with spaces"', '"string\n  with\n  some, lines"', 'anotherString']
```

[split but ignore seperators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785755/how-to-split-but-ignore-separators-in-quoted-strings-in-python)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Python's string replace. I.e.

```
raw_string = 'I'm string with \n new lines'

striped_new_lines = raw_string.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: It isnt a solution couse my new row delimiter is \n too. My program must ignore quoted \n only.

Comment: Then you could just write something like:
striped_new_lines = raw_string.replace('"\n"', '').